# Linq to SQL translation to SQL syntax

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do the following query in Linq

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.AnotherID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 T3
on T1.ID = T3.AnotherID
```

It works as expected in proper SQL syntax, but i'm having a hard time translating it to the corresponding Linq to SQL syntax.

How do i combine left join with an inner join?

Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var results = from t1 in Table1
   from t2 in Table2
   where t1.ID = t2.AnotherID
   join t3 in Table3 on t1.ID equals t3.AnotherID into joined
   from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new {t1, t2, t3 = j}
```